# Hide image from second and third div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following div structure

```
<div class="block_content">
    <img src="image1.png">
</div>
<div class="block_content">
    <img src="image2.png">
</div>
<div class="block_content">
    <img src="image3.png">
</div>
```

Now I want to hide image2 and image3 and my code is

```
 $(document).ready(function ($){
    $('div.block_content').each(function() 
    {
         if($("div.block_content:eq(1)").find('img').length)
         {
            $("div.block_content:eq(1)").addClass('hide-for-small');
         } 
         if($("div.block_content:eq(2)").find('img').length)
         {
            $("div.block_content:eq(2)").addClass('hide-for-small');
         } 
    });
  });
```

but the above jquery code does nothing.I have to check each div because sometimes the div can content text only.So in short if text then show all of three divs else hide last 2 divs.

Any help is highly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note, all your images are missing a closing quote. Also, you check `block_content` but the class is `block-content`.

Comment: The class is still an issue.

Comment: Which class you meant?

Comment: Why do it with jQuery? You can do this in CSS.

Comment: Your HTML uses `block_content` but your jQuery tries to select `block-content`. Dash versus underscore.

Comment: Sorry now fixed the class.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: Once you fix all the typos, it seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/em4oxh5f/. Are you sure your `hide-for-small` doesn't also have a typo?

Comment: Awesome @j08691 the class hide-for-small is perfect.Thank you so much.Can you please add it as answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: But I didn't do anything. I just showed that your code works. Provided the hide-for-small class exists.

Answer (score 2):

try [:nth-child - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```
$(".block_content:not(:first-child) img").hide();
```

or just css

```
.block_content:not(:first-child) img{ display:none}
```

if you don't want to use the `:not` try this

```
.block_content:nth-child(n+2) img{ display:none}
```

or this i hard but it will work too

```
img{ display:none}
.block_content:first-child img{ display:block}
```

or  use the `hidden` attr

```
<div id="block1" class="block_content">
    <img src="image1.png" />
</div>
<div id="block_2" class="block_content">
    <img src="image2.png" hidden />
</div>
<div id="block_3" class="block_content">
    <img src="image3.png" hidden />
</div>
```

Comment: The `:not` part is not fully supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("div.block_content").find("img").eq(1).hide(); // eq(1) mean second element to target
    $("div.block_content").find("img").eq(2).hide(); // eq(2) mean third element to target
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="block_content">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="https://i.imgur.com/OB0y6MR.jpg"> 
     <br>
    <p>Img 1 Show</p>
</div>
<div class="block_content">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="https://i.imgur.com/OnwEDW3.jpg">
    <br>
    <p>Img 2 Hide</p>
</div>
<div class="block_content">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="https://i.imgur.com/CzXTtJV.jpg">
    <br>
    <p>Img 3 Hide</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```